# Union Dataframes based on condition in spark(scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a folder which consists of 4 subfolders which contains parquet files
Folder->A.parquet,B.parquet,C.parquet,D.parquet(subfolders). My requirement is I want to union data frames based on file Names I provide to the method.
I am doing it with code

```
val df = listDirectoriesGetWantedFile(folderPath,sqlContext,A,B)
def listDirectoriesGetWantedFile(folderPath: String, sqlContext: SQLContext, str1: String, str2: String): DataFrame = {
    var df: DataFrame = null
    val sb = new StringBuilder
    sb.setLength(0)
    var done = false
    val path = new Path(folderPath)
    if (fileSystem.isDirectory(path)) {
        var files = fileSystem.listStatus(path)
        for (file <- files) {
        if (file.getPath.getName.contains(str) && !done) {
          sb.append(file.getPath.toString())
          sb.append(",")
          done = true
        } else if (file.getPath.getName.contains(str2)) {
          sb.append(file.getPath.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to split the sb and then union the dataframes. Which I am unable to find the solution. How can I approach it and solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could simply do something like this :

```
def listDirectoriesGetWantedFile(path: String, 
                                 sqlContext: SQLContext, 
                                 folder1: String, 
                                 folder2: String): DataFrame = {
  val df1 = sqlContext.read.parquet(s"$path/$folder1")
  val df2 = sqlContext.read.parquet(s"$path/$folder2")
  df1.union(df2)
}
```

---

**EDIT**

By using Hadoop FileSystem, you can check path existence on your folders. So you may try something like that :

```
def listDirectoriesGetWantedFile(path: String, sqlContext: SQLContext, folders: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
    val conf = new Configuration()
    val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)

    val existingFolders = folders
      .map(folder => new Path(s"$path/$folder"))
      .filter(fs.exists(_))
      .map(_.toString)

    if (existingFolders.isEmpty) {
      sqlContext.emptyDataFrame
    } else {
      sqlContext.read.parquet(existingFolders: _*)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I need validation some times folder1 or folder 2 might not exists then reading the parquet file will through me error